# Не добавляются данные в БД

Tags: php, mysqli

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, где находится ошибка.
Проверяю через терминал `SELECT * FROM catalog;` 
Таблица пуста.

**config.inc.php**

```
<?php
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define ("DB_LOGIN", "root");
define ("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
define ("DB_NAME", "eshop");
define ("ORDERS_LOG", "orders.log");

$basket = array();

$count = 0;

$link = mysqli_connect(
  DB_HOST,
  DB_LOGIN,
  DB_PASSWORD,
  DB_NAME
) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

**lib.inc.php**

```
<?php
function addItemToCatalog($title, $author, $pubyear, $price) {
  global $link;
  $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog (title, author, pubyear, price)
                  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
  if (!$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
    return false;
  }
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssii", $title, $author, $pubyear, $price);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  return true;
}

function filter($str, $type="s") {
  switch ($type) {
    case "s":
      return mysqli_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($str)));
      break;
    case "i":
      return (int)$str;
      break;
  }
}
```

**add2cat.php**

```
<?
require "secure/session.inc.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Форма добавления товара в каталог</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="save2cat.php" method="post">
        <p>Название: <input type="text" name="title" size="100">
        <p>Автор: <input type="text" name="author" size="50">
        <p>Год издания: <input type="text" name="pubyear" size="4">
        <p>Цена: <input type="text" name="price" size="6"> руб.
        <p><input type="submit" value="Добавить">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**save2cat.php**

```
<?php
    // подключение библиотек
    require "secure/session.inc.php";
    require "../inc/lib.inc.php";
    require "../inc/config.inc.php";

$title = filter($_POST["title"]);
$author = filter($_POST["author"]);
$pubyear = filter($_POST["pubyear"]);
$price = filter($_POST["price"]);

if (!addItemToCatalog($title, $author, $pubyear, $price)) {
    echo "Произошла ошибка";
} else {
    header("Location: add2cat.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Добавьте следующий код в начало файла save2cat.php и приведите текст ошибки
`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Rikaz 
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP/files/eshop/inc/lib.inc.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP/files/eshop/inc/lib.inc.php on line 18

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP/files/eshop/inc/lib.inc.php:18) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/files/eshop/admin/save2cat.php on line 16

Comment: @rikaz Нашел ошибку) Спасибо большое

Comment: Всегда рад помочь)

Comment: Кстати, зачем вообще нужен real_escape_string. вы же используете привязку пенременных, значит никакого экранирования строк при передаче не требуется

Comment: @mike мне говорили, что нужно всегда использовать эту функцию)

Comment: @JasHakimov Это говорят люди, которые не пользуются привязкой переменных. Они подставляют переменные прямо в текст, им нужно эскейпить. Хотя на самом деле нужно делать именно как вы, использовать привязку, так надежнее.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, буду иметь в виду!